# Visualizing items frequently purchased together

Tags: python, r, data-mining, visualization, association-rules

I have a dataset in following structure inserted in a CSV file:

```
Banana  Water   Rice
Rice    Water
Bread   Banana  Juice
```

Each row indicates a collection of items that were purchased together.  For example, the first row denotes that the items `Banana`, `Water`, and `Rice` were purchased together.

I want to create a visualization like the following:

[image: example visualization]

This is basically a grid chart but I need some tool (maybe Python or R) that  can read the input structure and produce a chart like the above as output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you probably want is a discrete version of a heat map.  For example, see below.  The red colors indicate the most commonly purchased together, while green cells are never purchased together.
 [image: heat map]

This is actually fairly easy to put together with Pandas DataFrames and matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg') # Write figure to disk instead of displaying (for Windows Subsystem for Linux)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

####
# Get data into a data frame
####
data = [
  ['Banana', 'Water', 'Rice'],
  ['Rice', 'Water'],
  ['Bread', 'Banana', 'Juice'],
]

# Convert the input into a 2D dictionary
freqMap = {}
for line in data:
  for item in line:
    if not item in freqMap:
      freqMap[item] = {}

    for other_item in line:
      if not other_item in freqMap:
        freqMap[other_item] = {}

      freqMap[item][other_item] = freqMap[item].get(other_item, 0) + 1
      freqMap[other_item][item] = freqMap[other_item].get(item, 0) + 1

df = DataFrame(freqMap).T.fillna(0)
print (df)

#####
# Create the plot
#####
plt.pcolormesh(df, edgecolors='black')
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.index), 1), df.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(df.columns), 1), df.columns)
plt.savefig('plot.png')
```

Comment: Many thanks :) Can I create this using Spark Mllib?

Comment: @João_testeSW You probably can, but I'm unfamiliar with Spark.

Comment: did you recommend any IDE for executing this code?

Comment: @João_testeSW If you save this in a file as "somescript.py", you can run it with "python3 somescript.py" on the terminal.  No IDE needed, but if you load it into some Python-capable IDE it should run.

Comment: thanks ;) I'll see if I can use it into Pyspark, if yes then I can edit the post with the solution ;)

Comment: only one doubt: how can apply that code if I have the sequence in a CSV? I've edited below.

Comment: @João_testeSW There are many examples of reading CSV files with Python--they have a really good CSV library for such things.  I recommend you follow a more in-depth tutorial than I could provide here.

Answer (score 3):

For `R`, you can use library `ArulesViz`. There is nice [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesViz/vignettes/arulesViz.pdf) and on the page 12, there is example how to create this kind of visualization.

The code for that is as simple as this:

```
plot(rules, method="grouped")
```

Comment: While it's not what the OP is looking for, there's a great example visualization using this library here: https://algobeans.com/2016/04/01/association-rules-and-the-apriori-algorithm/

Answer (score 0):

With [Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/) in [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/).

```
data = {{"Banana", "Water", "Rice"},
        {"Rice", "Water"},
        {"Bread", "Banana", "Juice"}};
```

Get pairwise counts.

```
counts = Sort /@ Flatten[Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ data, 1] // Tally
```

> ```
> {{{"Banana", "Water"}, 1}, {{"Banana", "Rice"}, 1}, 
>  {{"Rice", "Water"}, 2}, {{"Banana", "Bread"}, 1}, 
>  {{"Bread", "Juice"}, 1}, {{"Banana", "Juice"}, 1}}
> ```

Get indices for named ticks.

```
indices = Thread[# -> Range[Length@#]] &@Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[data]
```

> ```
> {"Banana" -> 1, "Bread" -> 2, "Juice" -> 3, "Rice" -> 4, "Water" -> 5}
> ```

Plot with `MatrixPlot` using `SparseArray`. Could also use `ArrayPlot`.

```
MatrixPlot[
 SparseArray[Rule @@@ counts /. indices, ConstantArray[Length@indices, 2]],
 FrameTicks -> With[{t = {#2, #1} & @@@ indices}, {{t, None}, {t, None}}],
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

Note that it is upper-triangular.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in python with the seaborn visualization library (built on top of matplotlib).

```
data = [
  ['Banana', 'Water', 'Rice'],
  ['Rice', 'Water'],
  ['Bread', 'Banana', 'Juice'],
]

# Pull out combinations
from itertools import combinations
data_pairs = []
for d in data:
    data_pairs += [list(sorted(x)) + [1] for x in combinations(d, 2)]
    # Add reverse as well (this will mirror the heatmap)
    data_pairs += [list(sorted(x))[::-1] + [1] for x in combinations(d, 2)]

# Shape into dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data_pairs)
df_zeros = pd.DataFrame([list(x) + [0] for x in combinations(df[[0, 1]].values.flatten(), 2)])
df = pd.concat((df, df_zeros))
df = df.groupby([0, 1])[2].sum().reset_index().pivot(0, 1, 2).fillna(0)

import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.pyplot import plt
sns.heatmap(df, cmap='YlGnBu')
plt.show()
```

The final dataframe `df` looks like this:

[image]

and the resulting visualization is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use networkx to create a graph like structure.

Example : using python networkx package

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G1 = nx.DiGraph()
color_map = []
N = 50
colors = np.random.rand(N)
strs = ['r0', 'r1']
for i in range(2):
    G1.add_nodes_from('r'+str(i))
    for a in top_rules.iloc[i]['antecedents']:
        G1.add_nodes_from([a])
        G1.add_edge(a, 'r'+str(i), color = colors[i], weight = 2)
    for c in top_rules.iloc[i]['consequents']:
        G1.add_nodes_from([c])
        G1.add_edge('r'+str(i), c, color = colors[i], weight = 2)
for node in G1:
    found_a_string = False
    for item in strs:
        if node == item:
            found_a_string = True
    if found_a_string:
        color_map.append('red')
    else:
        color_map.append('black')
edges = G1.edges()
print(edges)
colors = [G1[u][v]['color'] for u,v in edges]
weights = [G1[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]
pos = nx.spring_layout(G1, k = 16, scale = 1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (4,4))
nx.draw(G1, pos, edges, node_color = color_map, edge_color = colors, width = weights, font_size = 16, with_labels = False)
for p in pos:
    pos[p][1] += 0.07
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G1, pos)
```