# Create data visualization for unstructured data - Basket Market Analysis

Tags: visualization, association-rules, market-basket-analysis

I have this dataset (just a sample):

```
product1,product2,product3
product1,product4
product1,product2
product4,product3,product1,product2
```

The products are grouped by transaction. I want to create some data visualization using this dataset but I don't any tool or any type of visualization that allows creating some visualization with this structure...

Anyone can suggest me an option?

Thanks!

I feel desperate because they can not find anything that suits this data structure

Comment: But what do you want this visualisation for? What are you trying to find out? A visualisation is an answer to a question, and you haven't told us the question.

Comment: @Spacedman  
I want to find the strenght like a heat-map or a grid chart...A visualization that allows me to conclude what the most frequently item purchase together...but with this strucuture I can't find any tool

Comment: a similar question was asked recently [here](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/14409/23305), this would work for a not too large number of items

Comment: How can a visualisation be any better than a sorted table of pair-wise occurrences?

Comment: @Spacedman Which type of tool/language did you recommend to produce that table?

Comment: Any language really. What do you know? Its a one-liner in the Unix shell using `awk`, for example: `awk -F, '{split($0,a,",");asort(a);for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++){print a[i],a[j]}} }' < sample.txt | sort | uniq -c| sort -rn` - produces a list of pairs with occurrence counts.

Comment: I guess you can use word cloud if you want to group by transaction for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering data stored in CSV format like below without headers you can use below R code to plot simple bar chart. It will plot occurrences of transactions grouped by unique transactions.

```
product1,product2,product3
product1,product4
product1,product2
product4,product3,product1,product2
product1,product2,product3
product1,product4
product1,product4
```

R Code -

```
transactions <- read.csv("filepath/transactions.csv", header = FALSE)
transactions$V1
plot(transactions$V1)
```

Bar Chart-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***[plotly](https://plot.ly/)*** for making interactive visualization and charts. You can also give a try to ***Linkurious***.
Hope it helps.
Cheers! :)